# Confirmation missing in FormFlow

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, formflow

I have followed the HotelBol tutorial and the main idea is that I have a FormFlow. Following a model, I add a field, named BedSize (which is an enum) then I add all the remaining fields. So far so good, everything works fine.

```
public static IForm<RoomReservation> BuildForm()
{
    return new FormBuilder<RoomReservation>()
        .Message("Welcome to the hotel reservation bot!")
        .Field(nameof(BedSize))
        .AddRemainingFields()
        .Build();
}
```

My problem is that I want in the end to have the default confirmation, from the confirmation message. The problem I face is that the Build method from the FormBuilder has that confirmation, but to me, it does not appear.

However, if I change my code to this:

```
public static IForm<RoomReservation> BuildForm()
{
    return new FormBuilder<RoomReservation>()
        .Message("Welcome to the hotel reservation bot!")
        .Build();
}
```

it also triggers the confirmation message. Is there something that I am missing? I want to know why adding the `.Field` and/or `.AddRemainingFields` methods make the confirmation message dissapear.

Comment: are you seeing any errors at all?

Comment: @JasonSowers No errors, everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Every example I have seen uses a `.Confirm()` with a custom message.  When using `.Field()` or `.AddRemainingFields()` See the annotated sandwich bot below

For example in our formflow sample for a [Simple sanwich bot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/5cf71c742f27d89e9dbc4076f850122bd6edac11/CSharp/Samples/SimpleSandwichBot/Sandwich.cs) does not use `.Field()` or `.AddRemainingFields()` and the auto confirm work. Whereas [Annotated Shandwich Bot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/5cf71c742f27d89e9dbc4076f850122bd6edac11/CSharp/Samples/SimpleSandwichBot/Sandwich.cs) uses `.Field()` and `.AddRemainingFields()` `.Confirm` is used.

Basically it looks like you need to come up with a custom confirm implementation where you use `.Field()` and `.AddRemainingFields()` good luck.

Comment: I saw the example, but my concern is that if you dig deeper into the chatbot implementation, you will see the class which at `.Build()` is responsible for calling in the end the `.Confirm()` extension method, but it seems that when using some extra extension methods, the `.Build()` does not behave as written and some middleware interferes with it.